# Bootstrap: centering content in Nav and changing default beavior on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried adding floats and using some Bootstrap classes to try and get it to work to no avail. Not sure what I'm missing. I would like to make the ul or all the items centered. Below is the nav markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/1489/

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

Also, on smaller screens, the nav's default behavior is to stack on top of each other. I wanted to make it so that the active link is the only one shown (or maybe with another link), but it can be scrolled horizontally for the other links. I am planning on using Scrollspy so active links are updated automatically if that makes a difference. Not sure how to approach that - any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `li` elements are block-level (`display :block` is applied through Bootstrap's CSS), all you need to do is add `text-align: center` on the `ul`:

```
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've created an updated fiddle showcasing this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pkfz49fa/).

Not sure about the ScrollSpy effect, but I'd assume that you can simply pass through the collection of links as an argument into the parameters.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend using 'bootstrap navbar example'(http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). Specifically, in your situation i'd use this modified version:

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>        
                </ul>                
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>                  
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```